# How can I shorten method with if-statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to shorten this method.
Could you tell me how can I make it? I tried somehow, but with a bad result. 
`Books` list length is not known. It can be 10, but it can be 0 also. I need 3 books if they exist.

```
public List<Book> findTheLatest3Books() {
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>(bookRepository.findAllByOrderByDateOfCreation());
    List<Book> listOf3LatestBooks = new ArrayList<>();
    if (books.size() >= 3) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (books.get(i).isAvailable()) {
                listOf3LatestBooks.add(books.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    if (books.size() == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (books.get(i).isAvailable()) {
                listOf3LatestBooks.add(books.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    if (books.size() == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            if (books.get(i).isAvailable()) {
                listOf3LatestBooks.add(books.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    if (books.size() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No books in DB");
    }
    return listOf3LatestBooks;
}
```

Comment: This is a basic question that you are asking. You should really try to find a way to do it yourself before asking the community.

Comment: you are tipically asking someone to do your homework... you never going to improve this way... is is a shame that people answer this and colaborate to the "formation" of poor developers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `books.size() < 3`, you go with the size, otherwise you go with `3`.

```
if (books.isEmpty()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No books in DB");
}

final int n = books.size() >= 3 ? 3 : books.size();

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (books.get(i).isAvailable()) {
        listOf3LatestBooks.add(books.get(i));
    }
}
```

It looks like you utilise a custom Spring JPA repository method. You could fetch only the first 3 records, [by limiting query results.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result)

Comment: that is true. I used `findFirst3ByOrderByDateOfCreation` and it works. Dont know which way is better and more efficient?

Comment: @lilikaa1 `findFirst3ByOrderByDateOfCreation` is better and more efficient. There could be a ton of books, while you need 3. The method name is pretty expressive.

Comment: `final int n = books.size() >= 3 ? 3 : books.size();` could be simplified to --> `final int n = Math.min(3, books.size())`. matter of choice though i guess.

Answer (score 5):

Via stream:

```
List<Book> books = ...    
if (books.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No books in DB");            
return books.stream() // Stream<Book>
            .limit(3) // truncated to be no longer than 3 in length.
            .filter(Book::isAvailable) // keep only books that are available               
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

This uses a stream truncating the stream to be no longer than `3` in length and then filters to retain the books that are available.

Comment: If books has length of 2 elements, everything is gonna be fine?

Comment: @lilikaa1 yes, if the items in the list is less than `3` then it will take that amount. so if it's `2` then it will take `2`

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the condition `i < 3 && i < books.size()` at the `for` statement:

```
public List<Book> findTheLatest3Books() {
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(bookRepository.findAllByOrderByDateOfCreation());
    List<Book> listOf3LatestBooks = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3 && i < books.size(); i++) {
        if (books.get(i).isAvailable()) {
            listOf3LatestBooks.add(books.get(i));
        }
    }

    if (books.size() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No books in DB");
    }
    return listOf3LatestBooks;
}
```